# Adding Data to the multiple column in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Hi I am working on a project and I need to do some addition while working on a table.

like I have to fill the three fields and change the status to 2 using checkbox Array. I tried it all but with no luck. Kindly look into it and Let me know the changes I can Do.

My Model CustomerLoad.php is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerLoad extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'driver_id',
        'vehicle_id',
        'company_id',
        'customer_id',
        'package_type',
        'from',
        'to',
        'in_mile',
        'weight',
        'height',
        'width',
        'length',
        'rate',
        'duration_text',
        'ticket_number',
        'status_id'
    ];

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
    }
}
```

My Controller for creating the page is Like this

```
public function create()
    {
        $csloads = CustomerLoad::paginate(4);
        $driver = Driver::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
        $vehicle = Vehicle::pluck('vin', 'id')->all();
        $company = Company::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
        return view('customerload.create', compact('csloads', 'driver', 'vehicle', 'company'));
    }
```

for storing it

```
public function updatecsloads(Request $request)
    {
        if(isset($request->update_all) && !empty($request->checkBoxArray)){
            $csloads = CustomerLoad::findOrFail($request->checkBoxArray);
            foreach($csloads as $csload){
                $input = $request->all();
                dd($input);
                // $csload->update($input);
            }
            // return redirect()->back();
        // } else {
            // return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

My View is like

```
<div class="card">
          <div class="card-header card-header-rose card-header-text">
            <div class="card-ttle">
              <h4 class="card-text">Allocate Loads</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            {!! Form::model(['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['CustomerLoadsController@updatecsloads']]) !!}
            <div class='form-group'>
              {!! Form::select('checkBoxArray', ['' => 'Allocate'], null, ['class' => 'selectpicker form-control', 'data-style'=>'btn btn-link', 'id'=>''])!!}
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
            {!! Form::submit('Allocate Loads', ['class'=>'btn btn-rose pull-right']) !!}
            </div>            
            @if(count($csloads) > 0)
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="options"></th>
                    <th>Driver Name</th>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Vehicle Vin Number</th>
                    <th>Origin</th>
                    <th>Destination</th>
                    <th>Package Type</th>
                    <th>Dimensions</th>
                    <th>Weight</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                  
                  @foreach($csloads as $csload)
                  @if($csload->status_id == 1)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{‌{$csload->id}}</td>
                    <td><input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]" value="{‌{$csload->status ? $csload->status->id == 2 : $csload->status->id == 1}}"></td>
                    <td>{!! Form::select('driver_id', ['' => 'Choose Driver Name'] + $driver, null, ['class' => 'selectpicker form-control', 'data-style'=>'btn btn-link', 'id'=>'exampleFormControlSelect1'])!!}</td>
                    <td>{!! Form::select('company_id', ['' => 'Choose Company Name'] + $company, null, ['class' => 'selectpicker form-control', 'data-style'=>'btn btn-link', 'id'=>'exampleFormControlSelect1'])!!}</td>
                    <td>{!! Form::select('vehicle_id', ['' => 'Choose Vehicle Vin Number'] + $vehicle, null, ['class' => 'selectpicker form-control', 'data-style'=>'btn btn-link', 'id'=>'exampleFormControlSelect1'])!!}</td>
                    <td>{‌{$csload->from}}</td>
                    <td>{‌{$csload->to}}</td>
                    <td>{‌{$csload->package_type}}</td>
                    <td>{‌{$csload->length}}x{‌{$csload->width}}x{‌{$csload->height}}</td>
                    <td>{‌{$csload->weight}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>              
            </div>
            @else
            <h1 class="text-center">No Loads Found</h1>
            @endif
            {!! Form::close() !!}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am struck in the project kindly answer the question as soon as you can I shall be really obliged.

Thanks in advance

From Munish Rana

Love your Work

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: which fields do you mean by `three` ?

Comment: the three fields are driver_id, company_id, vehicle id

Comment: the error message is method not allowed

Answer (score 0):

change 'method' => 'PATCH' to 'POST'
and add  {{ method_field('PATCH') }} to form field like this

```
<form method="POST" action="your url" >
{{csrf_field()}}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
</form>
```